Why UITextField with contentType .newPassword loses its keyboard type when unfocused and then focused again?
I have three UITextField views: oldPassword, newPassword, confirmPassword which look like this:

Each of them has defined like this:
let oldView = UITextField()
oldView.textContentType = .password
oldView.isSecureTextEntry = true

let newView = UITextField()
newView.textContentType = .newPassword
newView.isSecureTextEntry = true

let confirmView = UITextField()
confirmView.textContentType = .newPassword
confirmView.isSecureTextEntry = true

There is also hidden UITextField for email, but it doesn't matter here.
After I type something in oldPassword, and focus on newPassword either confirmPassword it looks like this:

Then I select Choose my own password and type something in both newPassword and confirmPassword. Everything is fine, keyboard is normal.

But now here comes the issue: I just focus keyboard on first oldPassword and then on last confirmPassword. Look at the keyboard.

Why it still trying to suggest? There should be normal keyboard as it is not empty. How to fix that?

"There should be normal keyboard as it is not empty." Should it, though? Is this officially documented anywhere? If not, I think it is perfectly normal for it to do what it is currently doing.
